# dojo dgrid how to programmatically scroll/jump to a row in the grid

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I have a single page app that has a dojo dgrid grid and a map.  All the elements on the map appear in the dgrid grid.  When a user clicks on an item on the map, I would like to programmatically jump/scroll to the element in the dgrid grid.  I haven't come across any documentation that explains how to do this.  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That depends...  are you lazily rendering items in the grid, or rendering everything at once?  If the former, do you have some way of knowing *where* in the grid an item appears if it hasn't actually been loaded/rendered in it?

Comment: Ken, not sure I understand the question, all the items are loaded in the backing dstore, and I am not using pagination in the grid.                                                                                                I just ran across the following link:  https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/342

Comment: I presume then that you're using `OnDemandGrid`, which lazily renders items (as opposed to e.g. the single-query mixin in the tutorials).  The reason that question matters is you're going to have to know where in the store the item exists (based on whatever you're sorting by), even if it's not currently rendered, and then you'll need to calculate the pixel offset that equates to and call `scrollTo` to scroll it into view and load it.  If it's already rendered, the problem is more trivial since you can ostensibly just call `scrollIntoView` on the row element.